# Odeint for projectile motion

Tags: python, plot, odeint

I have plotted the projectile motion given initial conditions.

What I'm stuck on is trying to make tmax dependent on the initial conditions so if you change the initial conditions tmax changes to a reasonable value. Secondly How would I find the distance to impact, the time of flight and the velocity at impact. These all would depend on when y becomes zero but IDK how to use that info.
Here is my code. Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c=0.65   #Constant friction term
m=0.1    #Object's mass
g=9.81   #Gravitational acceleration
theta=50 #Angle
V0=10    #Initial Velocity
Vx0=np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta))*V0  #Calculates initial speed along the x-axis
Vy0=np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta))*V0  #Calculates initial speed along the y-axis

t0 = 0.0  #Initial time
tmax=1    #Final time
steps=20  #Number of time step
tAF = np.linspace(t0, tmax, steps)# Creates a 1-D array of time values

y0AF = [0.0, Vx0, 0.0, Vy0] #Initial condition for x-position, V along x, y-position, V along y 

def derivative(yAF,tF):     #Function which calculates the derivatives 
    Vx = yAF[1]             #Element in array for the velocity along x axis
    Vy = yAF[3]             #Element in array for the velocity along y axis
    return [Vx, -c*Vx/m, Vy, -g-c*Vy/m]  #Function outputs [dx/dt, dVx/dt, dy/dt, dVy/dt]

yM = odeint(derivative, y0AF, tAF)       #Array with the solution for the differential equation

plt.plot(yM[:,0],yM[:,2], '.')  #Plots y over x
plt.xlabel('x-distance'), plt.ylabel('y-distance')
plt.show()
MAXy=np.amax(yM[:,2])
print('Maximum height reached is',MAXy)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to integrate the differential equations all in one use of `odeint()`, you can use multiple steps, changing the initial conditions to continue the integration, e.g. by replacing the line:

```
yM = odeint(derivative, y0AF, tAF)
```

... with something like:

```
y = np.array([y0AF])
tLargeStep = 0.3
i = 0

while 1:
    tAF = np.linspace(i*tLargeStep, (i+1)*tLargeStep, steps)
    yM = odeint(derivative, y[-1,:], tAF)
    y = np.concatenate((y,yM[1:,:]))
    if y[-1,2] < 0:
        break
    i += 1

plt.plot(y[:,0],y[:,2], '.')  #Plots y over x
plt.xlabel('x-distance'), plt.ylabel('y-distance')
plt.show()
```

In this case, the integration will continue large step by large step until `y` is less than zero at the end of a large step.

Having obtained the data in `y`, you could use `numpy.interpolate()` on those data to find the distance to impact, the time of flight and the velocity at impact.

Alternatively, if you use `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp()` instead of `odeint()`, `solve_ivp()` allows you to specify events to track, and to make some of those events terminal, i.e. to make the solver stop computing when the specified event occurs.